# React - Type '(studentIds: Student[])' is missing the following properties from type 'Stduent[]' length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more. [2740]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm getting an error that says:

```
Type '(studentIds: string[]) => Promise<void>' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': 
    pop, push, concat, join, and 28 more.ts(2740)
StudentModal.tsx(143, 27): The expected type comes from property 'students' which is declared here on 
    type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

My component has `props` defined as:

```
interface Props {
  isOpen: boolean;
  students: Array<Student['id']>;
  onStudents: () => void;
  onClose: () => void;
}
```

It is called as:

```
<StudentModal
   isOpen={isOpenStudentsModal}
   students={getStudents}
   onStudents={studentCallback}
   onClose={studentToggle}    
 />
```

whereas `getStudents` is defined as:

```
export const getStudents = async(studentIds: Array<Student['id']>) : Promise<void> =>
{
 // service call to get student ids
};
```

As far as I can see, parameter list on `getStudents` matches the one on the `Props` interface. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface defined students as

```
  students: Array<Student['id']>;
```

but when you render the component, you are passing in the function of getStudents

```
students={getStudents}
```

so the type you passed into the component is `(studentIds: string[]) => Promise<void>` and not `string[]`.

What the error is saying is that the prop passed in do not have array methods like pop/push.

Since `getStudents` is a async function, you probably need to store the result in the state, then pass that state into the Model.

For example,

```
function Main() {
  const [studentIds, setStudentIds] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getStudents().then(studentIds => setStudentIds(studentIds))
  }, []);

  return (
    <StudentModal
      students={studentIds}
      ...
    />
  );
}
```